# SpringMvc java.lang.NullPointerException When Posting Form To Server

Tags: java, forms, post, spring-mvc, nullpointerexception

I have a form with a user name field on it when i tab out of the field i use a **RESTFUL**  **Web**  **Service** that makes a call to a handler method in the controller. The method makes a call to a **DAO** class that checks the database if the user name exists.

This works fine, however when the form is posted to the server i call the same exact function i would call in the handler method however i get a **java.lang.NullPointerException** when it accesses the class that makes a call to the **DAO** object. So it does not even access the **DAO** object the second time.

I have exception handlers around the calls in all my classes that makes calls. Any ideas as to whats happening here why i would get the **java.lang.NullPointerException** the second time the function is called.Does this have anything to do with **Spring** instantiating **DAO** classes using a **Singleton** method or something to that effect? What can be done to resolve this?

**This is what happens the First Time The Method is called using the Web Service(this is suppose to happen):**

```
13011 [http-8084-2] INFO  com.crimetrack.jdbc.JdbcOfficersDAO  - Inside jdbcOfficersDAO
13031 [http-8084-2] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate  - Executing prepared SQL query
13034 [http-8084-2] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate  - Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT userName FROM crimetrack.tblofficers WHERE userName = ?]
13071 [http-8084-2] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils  - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
13496 [http-8084-2] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils  - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 1, parameter value [adminz], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type unknown
13534 [http-8084-2] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils  - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
13537 [http-8084-2] INFO  com.crimetrack.jdbc.JdbcOfficersDAO  - No username was found in exception
13537 [http-8084-2] INFO  com.crimetrack.service.ValidateUserNameManager  - UserName :adminz does NOT exist
```

**The Second time When The Form Is 'Post' and a validation method handles the form and calls the same method the web service would call:**

```
17199 [http-8084-2] INFO  com.crimetrack.service.OfficerRegistrationValidation  - UserName is not null so going to check if its valid for :adminz
17199 [http-8084-2] INFO  com.crimetrack.service.OfficerRegistrationValidation  - User Name in try.....catch block is adminz
17199 [http-8084-2] INFO  com.crimetrack.service.ValidateUserNameManager  - Inside Do UserNameExist about to validate with username : adminz
17199 [http-8084-2] INFO  com.crimetrack.service.ValidateUserNameManager  - UserName :adminz EXCEPTION OCCURED java.lang.NullPointerException
```

**ValidateUserNameManager.java**

```
public class ValidateUserNameManager implements ValidateUserNameIFace {

    private OfficersDAO officerDao;

    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());


    public boolean DoesUserNameExist(String userName) throws Exception {

        logger.info("Inside Do UserNameExist about to validate with username : " + userName);

        try{

            if(officerDao.OfficerExist(userName) == true){

                logger.info("UserName :" + userName + " does exist");
                return true;

            }else{
                logger.info("UserName :" + userName + " does NOT exist");
                return false;
            }


        }catch(Exception e){

            logger.info("UserName :" + userName + " EXCEPTION OCCURED " + e.toString());
            return false;
        }       

    }

    /**
     * @return the officerDao
     */
    public OfficersDAO getOfficerDao() {
        return officerDao;
    }

    /**
     * @param officerdao the officerDao to set
     */
    public void setOfficerDao(OfficersDAO officerDao) {
        this.officerDao = officerDao;
    }



}
```

**JdbcOfficersDAO.java**

```
public boolean OfficerExist(String userName){

    String dbUserName;

    try{

        logger.info("Inside jdbcOfficersDAO");


        String sql = "SELECT userName FROM crimetrack.tblofficers WHERE userName = ?";

        try{
            dbUserName = (String)getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, new Object[]{userName},String.class);
            logger.info("Just Returned from database");

        }catch(Exception e){
            logger.info("No username was found in exception");
            return false;
        }

        if(dbUserName == null){

            logger.info("Database did not find any matching records");
        }

        logger.info("after JdbcTemplate");

        if (dbUserName.equals(userName)) {

            logger.info("User Name Exists");
            return true;

        }else{
            logger.info("User Name Does NOT Exists");
            return false;
        }       

    }catch(Exception e){

        logger.info("Exception Message in JdbcOfficersDAO is "+e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

**OfficerRegistrationValidation.java**

```
public class OfficerRegistrationValidation implements Validator{

    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

    private ValidateUserNameManager validateUserNameManager;


    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {

        return Officers.class.equals(clazz);
    }


    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {

        Officers officer = (Officers) target;

        if (officer.getUserName() == null){

            errors.rejectValue("userName", "userName.required");

        }else{

            String userName = officer.getUserName();                    

            logger.info("UserName is not null so going to check if its valid for :" + userName);
            try {

                logger.info("User Name in try.....catch block is " + userName);

                if (validateUserNameManager.DoesUserNameExist(userName)== true){

                    errors.rejectValue("userName", "userName.exist");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.info("Error Occured When validating UserName");
                errors.rejectValue("userName", "userName.error");
            }

        }

        if(officer.getPassword()== null){
            errors.rejectValue("password", "password.required");
        }

        if(officer.getPassword2()== null){
            errors.rejectValue("password2", "password2.required");
        }


        if(officer.getfName() == null){
            errors.rejectValue("fName","fName.required");
        }

        if(officer.getlName() == null){

            errors.rejectValue("lName", "lName.required");
        }

        if (officer.getoName() == null){
            errors.rejectValue("oName", "oName.required");
        }

        if (officer.getEmailAdd() == null){
            errors.rejectValue("emailAdd", "emailAdd.required");
        }

        if (officer.getDob() == null){
            errors.rejectValue("dob", "dob.required");
        }

        if (officer.getGenderId().equals("A")){
            errors.rejectValue("genderId","genderId.required");
        }


        if(officer.getDivisionNo() == 1){

            errors.rejectValue("divisionNo", "divisionNo.required");
        }

        if(officer.getPositionId() == 1){

            errors.rejectValue("positionId", "positionId.required");
        }

        if (officer.getStartDate() == null){

            errors.rejectValue("startDate","startDate.required");
        }

        if(officer.getEndDate() == null){

            errors.rejectValue("endDate","endDate.required");
        }

        logger.info("The Gender ID is " + officer.getGenderId().toString());

        if(officer.getPhoneNo() == null){

            errors.rejectValue("phoneNo", "phoneNo.required");
        }

    }



    /**
     * @return the validateUserNameManager
     */
    public ValidateUserNameManager getValidateUserNameManager() {
        return validateUserNameManager;
    }


    /**
     * @param validateUserNameManager the validateUserNameManager to set
     */
    public void setValidateUserNameManager(
            ValidateUserNameManager validateUserNameManager) {
        this.validateUserNameManager = validateUserNameManager;
    }



}
```

**Update Error Log using Logger.Error("Message", e):**

```
39024 [http-8084-2] INFO  com.crimetrack.service.OfficerRegistrationValidation  - UserName is not null so going to check if its valid for :adminz
39025 [http-8084-2] INFO  com.crimetrack.service.OfficerRegistrationValidation  - User Name in try.....catch block is adminz
39025 [http-8084-2] ERROR com.crimetrack.service.OfficerRegistrationValidation  - Message
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.crimetrack.service.OfficerRegistrationValidation.validate(OfficerRegistrationValidation.java:47)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.validate(DataBinder.java:725)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doBind(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:815)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveHandlerArguments(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:367)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:171)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
39025 [http-8084-2] INFO  com.crimetrack.service.OfficerRegistrationValidation  - Error Occured When validating UserName
```

**UPDATED**

**ApplicationContext.xml**

```
<beans>
<!-- __________________________________________________________________________________________________ --> 

    <bean id="officerRegistrationValidation" class="com.crimetrack.service.OfficerRegistrationValidation">
            <property name="validateUserNameManager" ref="validateUserNameManager"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="validateUserNameManager" class="com.crimetrack.service.ValidateUserNameManager">
            <property name="officerDao" ref="officerDao"/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="officerDao" class="com.crimetrack.jdbc.JdbcOfficersDAO" >
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

<!-- __________________________________________________________________________________________________ --> 


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
            <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
            <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
            <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>
<!-- __________________________________________________________________________________________________ -->    

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" 
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
<!-- __________________________________________________________________________________________________ -->    

    <bean id="transactionManager" 
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>





  </beans>
```

**Servlet.xml**

```
<beans>
<!-- __________________________________________________________________________________________________ --> 

     <bean name="/hello.htm" class="com.crimetrack.web.CountryListController">
        <property name="countryManager" ref="countryManager"/>
     </bean>

    <bean name="/login.htm" class="com.crimetrack.web.AuthenticationController">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>  
    </bean>

    <bean name="/officer_registration.htm" class="com.crimetrack.web.OfficerRegistrationController">
        <property name="divisionManager" ref="divisionManager" />
        <property name="positionManager" ref="positionManager" />
        <property name="genderManager" ref="genderManager"/>
    </bean>

<!-- __________________________________________________________________________________________________ -->    

    <bean name="/validateUserName.htm" class="com.crimetrack.web.OfficerRegistrationController">

        <property name="validateUserNameManager" ref="validateUserNameManager"/>    

    </bean>




<!-- __________________________________________________________________________________________________ -->    

      <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>        
      </bean>



</beans>
```

Comment: Code and/or a stacktrace would help...

Comment: it depends on how you are injecting the DAO in each of the cases. If you can, put some code here to check what's wrong with it.

Comment: you should check where the NullPointerException is thrown. that's where spring cannot inject your dependency.

Comment: i added the stacktrace will upload some code shortly

Comment: Could you test to see what happens if you temporarily disable the web service and just do the post? from the log, it seems the user did not exist the first time and perhaps you are doing some sort of cleaning there?

Comment: @RezaGoodarzi No the user does not exist so false was suppose to be returned to me by the function in both cases. I am going to disable the web service and see what happens.

Comment: you throw away all the useful message (stack trace) about the exception when you log the last line in `com.crimetrack.service.ValidateUserNameManager`. Try using `logger.error("Message", ex)`

Comment: whenever an exception occurs and is likely to cause error, log it with error method and pass the exception along to log the stack trace. if you do not intend to handle the error and just to provide information, use info method.

Comment: @gigadot thank you i always wonder when i had to use those

Comment: @RezaGoodarzi i posted an update on my error log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forget to autowire the `officerDao` field in ValidateUserNameManager.java

Try adding `@Autowire` :

```
@Autowire
private OfficersDAO officerDao;
```

**Update:**

After you updated your stack trace, I think it's the `validateUserNameManager` field in OfficerRegistrationValidation.java which is not autowired. However, this depends on what the line 47 is in OfficerRegistrationValidation.java

Comment: I am not using the @Autowire annotation in my code anywhere because i find it confusing can you tell me the xml / old way of doing this.

Comment: sorry, I don't know the xml configuration. I find annotations are easy to understand and is the best way to config the classes.

Comment: I have the validateUserNameManager setters and getter created in the OfficerRegistrationValidation

Comment: that doesn't mean spring will automatically inject the dependency, does it? did you configure the xml to inject that explicitly?

Comment: yes once you create the setters and getters its suppose to preform the injection, i am looking at the servlet file now

Comment: no, it won't inject unless you tell it to do so. this is why i find autowire very useful. without it, i need to explicitly inject it using xml configuration.

Comment: yes u need to have the servlet file configured also with your xml configurations as well like setting the properties for the beans

Comment: I am getting the error in the OfficerRegistrationValidation just at this point  if (validateUserNameManager.DoesUserNameExist(userName)== true){............. the validateUserNameManager is injected properly but i get a NPE.

Comment: that's what i thought so. it wasn't injected by IoC from some reason. and there could be one of many reasons.

Comment: How did you get OfficerRegistrationValidation object? did you get this bean via IoC bean factory?

Comment: The problem was in instantiating the class i created a Factory bean to handle the instantiating.

Answer (score 0):

The OfficerRegistrationValidation class was being instantiated in every call to it a Factory bean should be applied to handle the invocation if this class:

```
public final class BeanFactory() {

    private static ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context;

    private static ClassPathXmlApplicationContext getContext() {
        if (context== null) {
            context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        }
        return context;
    }

    public static OfficerRegistrationValidation getOfficerRegistrationValidation() {
        return (OfficerRegistrationValidation) getContext().getBean("officerRegistrationValidation");
    }
}
```

In the controller make a call like : `BeanFactory.getOfficerRegistrationValidation().validate(....)

Comment: this is not a solution since you are creating new beans for every call  to `getOfficerRegistrationValidation`. this includes recreating the database objects which are every expensive and can cost error if some object are supposed to be created only once (singleton). you should find a way to make `OfficerRegistrationValidation` reusable and threadsafe so that you can have only one of it and inject this to wherever you want using only IoC.

Comment: @gigadot what should be the best approach would it mean using a singleton approach for instantiation?