# SpringMvc Instantiating Beans - Singleton

Tags: java, spring-mvc, singleton, nullpointerexception, factory-pattern

In the under mentioned code i created this because i was getting java.lang.NullPointerException see my error log under. When i implemented this it was fixed and it worked perfectly. However i was told by one of the members here that -

*"you are creating new beans for every call to getOfficerRegistrationValidation. this includes recreating the database objects which are every expensive and can cost error if some object are supposed to be created only once (singleton). you should find a way to make OfficerRegistrationValidation reusable and threadsafe so that you can have only one of it and inject this to wherever you want using only IoC"*

and i think hes right can someone tell me whats the best way to do this without having to instantiate all my beans again. I just want to instantiate only the certain beans and not run into this problem.

```
public final class BeanFactory() {

    private static ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context;

    private static ClassPathXmlApplicationContext getContext() {
        if (context== null) {
            context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        }
        return context;
    }

    public static OfficerRegistrationValidation getOfficerRegistrationValidation() {
        return (OfficerRegistrationValidation) getContext().getBean("officerRegistrationValidation");
    }
}
```

In the controller make a call like : `BeanFactory.getOfficerRegistrationValidation().validate(....)

**Error Log:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.crimetrack.service.OfficerRegistrationValidation.validate(OfficerRegistrationValidation.java:51)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.validate(DataBinder.java:725)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doBind(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:815)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveHandlerArguments(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:367)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:171)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to hazard a guess at what you are asking about (as your question doesn't provide your motivation for using a beanfactory and doesn't provide enough code to give a complete picture)...

Spring beans are by default instantiated as singletons. So you should be able to configure Spring to create your `OfficerRegistrationValidation` object using either XML or annotation (`@Component`) and then get it injected into your controller by using the `@Inject` annotation.

Annotations are the way to go - just make sure you have the following in your Spring config XML (`applicationContext.xml`):

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.acme.project" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Then simply add the `@Component` annotation to the class declaration of your `OfficerRegistrationValidation` class:

```
@Component
public class OfficerRegistrationValidation {
    // ...
}
```

and then in your controller, declare a field for your OfficerRegistrationValidation and annotate it thus:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @Inject
    private OfficerRegistrationValidation officerRegistrationValidation;
    // ...
}
```

Now you will have access to the `OfficerRegistrationValidation` singleton bean in your controller - only ~4 lines of code needed!

Comment: I've used the JSR330 `@Inject` annotation, Spring can use this or the more common `@Autowired` anntotation to do the same thing. Your choice.

Comment: i am using xml based configurations since i do not fully understand annotations so presently i am using fewer annotations kind of like a hybrid configuration. Using the xml configuration helps me to understand the wiring of the entire project. I still do not get the Autowired annotation thats why i used a hybrid i mainly use the Controller, RequestMapping and so on. Can you give me some advice on this.

Comment: This is my previous question on this forum that relates to the same issue i am asking about it contains all the code and explanations  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558476/springmvc-java-lang-nullpointerexception-when-posting-form-to-server/12589627#comment16968815_12589627

Comment: You are trying to read too much into annotations, they are dead simple. Spring simply looks for a instantiated bean of the right `type` an injects it. You can also provide named beans if there are more than one type available. E.g. `@Component("specificBeanType") public class GenericBeanType`. Which allows you to access that bean via its bean id. You can do the same thing with XML: `<bean id="officerRegistrationValidation" class="com.acme.services. OfficerRegistrationValidation"/>`.